# Xamarin Forms The type TouchEffect was not found

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to use this xaml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:skia="clr-namespace:SkiaSharp.Views.Forms;assembly=SkiaSharp.Views.Forms"
             xmlns:tt="clr-namespace:TouchTracking;assembly=TouchTracking"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="MyApp.MemeBuilder"
             BackgroundColor="#212121">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <Grid BackgroundColor="White">
            <skia:SKCanvasView x:Name="MyCanvas"
                           PaintSurface="OnCanvasViewPaintSurface" />
            <Grid.Effects>
                <tt:TouchEffect  Capture="True"
                            TouchAction="OnTouchEffectAction" />
            </Grid.Effects>
        </Grid>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

I installed skiasharp and the nuget-package TouchTracking, but I still get the error:

> The type tt:TouchEffect was not found

How can I fix this?

Comment: Close your IDE and reopen and do rebuild.

Comment: TouchTracking is not the nuget package in this case

Comment: After reopen and rebuild, still same error

Comment: you need to include TouchEffect.cs in your project - it is part of the sample project that you are copying from

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you are using Touch Tracking library in Forms. Your assembly reference is incorrect. Below one should work:

```
xmlns:tt="clr-namespace:TouchTracking.Forms;assembly=TouchTracking.Forms"
```

Also, make sure you install the "TouchTracking.Forms" nuget package instead "TouchTracking".

More info here : https://github.com/OndrejKunc/SkiaScene#touchtrackingforms